# How do I know that this key is a flat or sharp key? Piano

Tags: piano, practice

[image]

I am quite the beginner at the piano, and I only know where C,D,E,F,G,A,B is placed at the piano and on the grand staff of piano. I am using Synthesia to practice my rythm (and as a way to check that I am actually playing correctly), and I am not sure why that specific symbol is a sharp. It looks like a normal C to me.

Another example:

[image]

Comment: I just wanted to say that that music is notated very incorrectly and is going to confuse you.

Comment: @MattPutnam You are probably right. There are still a couple of symbols in there I don't know so they won't really confuse me at the moment. I just use the PC as a rhythm helper so I get it right anyway. I have only been playing for a little over 1 month. This song might be a couple of levels too high for me to play, but I love it so much I want to learn it quickly. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F0wieyNeCFw

Comment: @David "There are still a couple of symbols in there I don't know so they won't really confuse me at the moment." Almost **everything** in **both** your pictures of the music notation is incorrect (i.e. it doesn't follow the standard conventions). Wherever that software claims to be doing, it certainly isn't teaching you **how to read sheet music**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Left from 1/4 you can see two sharps, those two sharps mean that you need to press F# and C# where on the staff you have F and C.

This part is written in the key of [D Major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_major).

Comment: Thank you for that. I managed to play the whole play without looking at the bottom of my PC screen now.

Comment: you are welcome, don't forget to keep practicing, maybe get a tutor and some good books, it's pretty hard in the beginning but it gets easier, have fun

Comment: Just to add to @supreme-tg's answer: the two sharps for F and C at the start of the third bar - just before the 1/4 time signature - are called a "key signature." The accidentals (sharps/flats) of the key signature apply for the whole score unless a new key signature is given in a new bar.